# SwiftUI How to make CoreData list selectable and double clickable on macOS

Tags: macos, core-data, swiftui

I have a selectable and double clickable list of names.
I have a CoreData list of records that I cannot select or double click.

How do I make the CoreData list selectable and double clickable?

Here is the selectable list code I am using:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private static let values = ["Luke","Han","Chewie","Liea","R2D2"]
    
    @State private var selection: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                List(Self.values, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { name in
                    Text(name)
                        .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
                            print("double clicked")
                            selection = name
                        })
                        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                            print("single clicked")
                            selection = name
                        })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ManagedObject:

```
@objc(Enquiry)
public class Enquiry: NSManagedObject {

}
```

Here is my CoreData list that displays the list:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct EnquiryList: View
{
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    var enquiries: FetchRequest<Enquiry>
    
    init (uuid: UUID)
    {
        enquiries = FetchRequest<Enquiry>(entity: Enquiry.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "UUID == %@", uuid as CVarArg))
    }
    @State private var selection: Enquiry? = nil
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            ForEach(enquiries, id: \.self, selection: $selection)
            {enquiry in
                EnquiryListRow(enquiry: enquiry)
                    .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
                        print("double clicked")
                        selection = enquiry
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ForEach line gives the following error:

[image]

What am I missing? Ultimately I want to select the record and then open a window on the double click with the enquiry.

Changing the code based on Asperi's answer doesn't get me much further:

```
List(enquiries.wrappedValue, id: \.self, selection: $selection)
{enquiry in
    Text("Hello")
}
```

enquiries.wrappedValue.count shows that there are three records, but nothing is displayed. Moving it back to a ForEach will display Hello three times.

Comment: The second example is not working? The first one works fine for me

Comment: Yes that is my question. How to make the second example work like the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without your missing code it's a bit difficult to reproduce the error. However, I've written some code which you can copy&paste to get things working.

Please find my tested and working example below:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import CoreData

class PersistentContainer {
    public static var container: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        
        return container
    }()
    
    private init() {}
}

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    private var _context: NSManagedObjectContext
    @Published public var Enquiries: [Enquiry]
    
    init() {
        self._context = PersistentContainer.container.viewContext
        self.Enquiries = try! self._context.fetch(Enquiry.fetchRequest())
    }
}

struct EnquiryListRow: View {
    public var Enquiry: Enquiry
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(self.Enquiry.name ?? "(no name given)")")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = DataModel()
    @State private var selection: Enquiry? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        List(self.model.Enquiries, id: \.self, selection: self.$selection) { enquiry in
            EnquiryListRow(Enquiry: enquiry)
                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
                    print("double clicked")
                    self.selection = enquiry
                })
                .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                    print("single clicked")
                    self.selection = enquiry
                })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use List in second case as well - `ForEach` is just a dynamic group which does not have `selection` feature:

```
var body: some View
{
    VStack
    {
        List(selection: $selection)     // << here !!
        {ForEach(enquiries, id: \.self)
        {enquiry in
            EnquiryListRow(enquiry: enquiry)
                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
                    print("double clicked")
                    selection = enquiry
                })
        }}
    }
}
```

Comment: If I make that change I get Initializer 'init(_:id:selection:rowContent:)' requires that 'FetchRequest<Enquiry>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'. Any suggestions?

Comment: This didn't work. I had to use wrappedValue in the List to make it compile, but then it didn't show any rows. Reverting to ForEach (without the selection) did display the rows.

Comment: I dont have all your code, so cannot test, be try as updated - combine List and ForEach, if latter works for you.

Comment: Adding the List around the ForEach causes the rows to no longer be displayed.